# Ошибка при обращении к компоненту формы из потока(windows)

Tags: многопоточность, winforms, c++

Здравствуйте!

Помогите исправить ошибку:

```
 An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'richTextBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
```

Ошибка возникает при работе с потоком... У меня приложение-клиент, должно отправлять и принимать сообщения... Принимаю я эти сообщения в потоке:

```
File.cpp
        namespace Client_WFA {
        using namespace System;
        using namespace System::ComponentModel;
        using namespace System::Collections;
        using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
        using namespace System::Data;
        using namespace System::Drawing;
        using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

    void Form1::trdMethod(){
            while(....) {
            Invoke(myDelegate);
            }
            //Thread::Sleep(0); 
    }
    void Form1::delegation(){
         richTextBox1->Text=richTextBox1->Text+"\n"+systemstring;
    }

    Form1::Form1(void){
                InitializeComponent();
                trdc = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(this, &Form1::trdMethod));
                trdc->Start();
        }

    void Form1::InitializeComponent(void){
        // 
    // Form1
    // 
    this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
    this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
    this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(311, 272);
    this->Controls->Add(this->richTextBox2);
    this->Controls->Add(this->richTextBox1);
    this->Controls->Add(this->label4);
    this->Controls->Add(this->label3);
    this->Controls->Add(this->Send);
    this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
    this->FormBorderStyle = System::Windows::Forms::FormBorderStyle::Fixed3D;
    this->MaximizeBox = false;
    this->Name = L"Form1";
    this->Opacity = 0.7;
    this->Text = L"Client";
    this->FormClosing += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::FormClosingEventHandler(this, &Form1::Form1_FormClosing);
    this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::Form1_Load);
    this->ResumeLayout(false);
    this->PerformLayout();
    myDelegate = gcnew AddListItem( this, &Form1::delegation);//<==============

}

void Form1::Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {}
```

}

```
File.h
namespace Client_WFA {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    using namespace System::Threading;

    /// <summary>

    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
        String ^systemstring;
        private: Thread^ trdc;
        private: System::Void trdMethod();

        delegate void AddListItem();
        AddListItem^ myDelegate;
        void delegation();

    public:
        void socket_init();
        Form1(void);

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (trdc->IsAlive)// уничтожаем поток
                trdc->Abort();
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  Send;
    public: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label3;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label4;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox^  richTextBox1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox^  richTextBox2;

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void);
#pragma endregion
private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e);
};
}
```

Я понял, что программа не может менять значение компонента из потока... Как можно это исправить?

Comment: С визуальными компонентами можно работать только из того потока, в котором они созданы (UI-thread). В вашем случае попробуйте использовать метод Invoke у формы, на которой расположен richTextBox1. В метод Invoke надо передать делегата, который будет выполнен в UI-потоке. В коде делегата и нужно реализовать изменение значения контролов.

Comment: А можете примерно показать как это всё должно выглядеть или ссылку на хороший сайт дать?

Comment: В MSDN есть достаточно подробный пример, правда на буржуйском
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-2

Comment: Его-то и изучал, подправил код, получил другую ошибку: Additional information: Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.

Comment: ...
Invoke(myDelegate); //в потоке(тут ошибка)

  }
 
}
void Form1::delegation(){//не в потоке

  richTextBox1->Text=richTextBox1->Text+"\n"+systemstring;

}

Comment: По приведенному неполному листингу сложно судить из-за чего вылетает исключение. Могу посоветовать изучить похожий вопрос на SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808867/invoke-or-begininvoke-cannot-be-called-on-a-control-until-the-window-handle-has
либо статью вот эту статью на msdn
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx

Comment: Посмотрел, не помогло... привел наиболее полный код приложения, может теперь можно разглядеть в чем ошибка...